# sql query get all children and grandchildren

Tags: sql-server, tree-structure

What is proper way to get all children and grandchildren or n-generation children.
for children and grandchildren my query is like below:

```
SELECT e1.ID, e1.LName + ', '+e1.FName
  FROM lstEmp e1  INNER JOIN lstEmp e2 ON e1.Supervisor = e2.ID
  Where e2.Supervisor = 'xxxxxxx'
 UNION 
  SELECT distinct e2.ID, e2.LName + ', '+e2.FName
  FROM lstEmp e1  INNER JOIN lstEmp e2 ON e1.Supervisor = e2.ID
  Where e2.Supervisor = 'xxxxxxx'
```

my question:1)is this the proper way?
2) what if I need all children and grandchildren and (4,5..)n-generation children?

Comment: Can you make a Sql fiddle? [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Regarding getting grand-children: It depends on what database you are using (and the versions). Many newer databases support recursive table expressions, and some Oracle database support the `CONNECT BY` keyword.

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 r2

Comment: A recursiveCTE is about the best way to do this with the current structure.

Comment: @Sean, could you show me how to use recursiveCTE pls?

Comment: I can show you if can post ddl (create table statements) and sample data (insert statements). You can do this here or create a fiddle as already suggested. Of course our old friend google has TONS of examples. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following CTE starts with the row where `ID` = 'xxx'. Then, its children and grandchildren are selected by joining the `ID` with the `Supervisor`.

```
WITH grandchildren as
(
    SELECT e1.ID ID, e1.LName + ', '+e1.FName FullName, 0 as lvl
    FROM lstEmp e1
    WHERE e1.ID ='xxx'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e2.ID, e2.LName + ', '+e2.FName, lvl+1
    FROM lstEmp e2  
    INNER JOIN grandchildren g ON e2.Supervisor = g.LsuID
)
SELECT *
FROM grandchildren
ORDER BY lvl, ID;
```

Here's a [great reference on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx). There is a good example of selecting Managers and Direct Reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the table schema, I'd say the best way to handle this is to use a HierarchyId data type in your table which is designed for exactly the problem you're having. See the documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb677290.aspx and here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx for more info on that.

If you can't change the table, I would use a cursor within a stored procedure and return the results that way - Good example here: [T-SQL Stored Procedure for Looping a hierarchy with recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873829/t-sql-stored-procedure-for-looping-a-hierarchy-with-recursion)

Comment: Ugh!!! A cursor is about the slowest method I can think of for this with the exception of a while loop. The HierarchyID would work but even better would be to use nested sets.